# Should the [paranoid-sysadmin] be eliminated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just came across 4 questions tagged as [paranoid-sysadmin](/questions/tagged/paranoid-sysadmin). Although the questions seem serious and legitimate, the tag seems like a joke to me. I felt the urge to edit those questions and remove that tag, but I'm unsure if I should do it.

So my question is whether the [paranoid-sysadmin](/questions/tagged/paranoid-sysadmin) tag should be removed.

Comment: Myeah, as soon as it's no longer in read-only mode over on SO, I'd say those can go.

Comment: Paranoid sysadmin? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: If all the paranoid sysadmins are redundant then the world will fall apart @Yannis, but at least IE6 would be allowed to die :-).

Comment: @Yannis given the amount of bad sysadmins out there probably it would be redundant only in "paranoid good sysadmin" :-D

Comment: I'm afraid IE6 will be around even after the world falls apart @benisuǝqbackwards.

Comment: @Yannis Thinking of aliens visiting the ruins of our world and finding IE6 as our only legacy .... arghhh! .... *(runs away in terror)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tag is just a joke; I've removed it from all 4 questions and it'll be gone next tag cleanup.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Hail and praises to our lord Trogdor! BURN THEM ALL! :-D